# Connection refuse error while convert doc to pdf using jodconvertor

Tags: java, openoffice.org

I am getting error connection refused on below code

```
             OpenOfficeConnection connection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection(openOfficeServerPort);
              try
              {
                connection.connect();

                 DocumentConverter converter = new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(connection);
                 converter.convert(inputFile, outputFile);

                connection.disconnect();
                 return "Sucess  " + DestinationPath + DestinationFileName;
               }
               catch (Exception localException1) {
                    return "failed in connection.connect()"+localException1;
               }
```